# Android: progressdailog not working properly

Tags: android, progressdialog

In my app when i click on a icon, i implemented a posting on fb dailog, but it is taking time to load the fbdailog, i am using the progressDailog ,code as follows

```
ImageView faceBookIntegration = (ImageView) activity
                .findViewById(R.id.facebookintegration);
        faceBookIntegration.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Constants.isLayoutTouched = true;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    CityAttractions.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Dialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CityAttractions.this, "","Please wait...", true);
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    Intent menuSettingsIntent = new Intent(CityAttractions.this, ShareOnFacebook.class);
                    menuSettingsIntent.putExtra("facebookMessage", "Msg");
                    startActivity(new Intent(menuSettingsIntent).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT));


                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

facing two issues when i click the icon iam getting the progressdailog (here the spinner is not spinning), and later getting the fbdailog which is fine , after i cancel the fbdailog i still see the progress dailog , how to close the progressdailog after fb dailog is done
Any help is appreciated

Comment: maybe, cause you do it in action_down event?

Comment: pass any variable from your fbdialog and while returning check for it. and dismiss the dialog

Comment: @nick..new to this can u suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you are doing a big mistake. ProgressDialog.show() will create ProgressDialog Instance and show the Dialog already. You are assigning the same dialog to another Dialog and showing it again. So It shows double time.

Change your code to

```
Dialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CityAttractions.this, "","Please wait...", true);
```

Now dialog will have the reference of ProgressDialog it was showing and you can dismiss once your task is done.

Comment: i can still see the progressdailog after closing the fbdailog..do ineed to call dialog.dismiss();???

Comment: hey that is what I have mentioned in my answer, that you need to call dialog.dismiss() once your task is finished.

Comment: where should i call dismiss(), my task is ending in another activity...??

Comment: your code is confusing and I am unable to know why you are showing progress dialog.

Comment: its taking time to load the fbdailog(its a custom dailog) so in meanwhile i wanna show progressdailog..

Comment: you see iam passing intent to other activity , that activity has fbdailog, when i close the dailog in that activity i still see the progress dailog..thats the problem

Comment: Then it is not possible. you are starting ProgressDialog in one activity which is sent to backstack by starting the FB Activity. So it is not possible to dismiss. Do the progressDialog.show in the FB Activity

Comment: not sure where to put the code...http://pastebin.com/zKSXziJn  this is my fbsctivity which has the customdailog, please tell where can i start progressdailog

Comment: tried ..not working..this is my complete fbactivity  http://pastebin.com/kCXMvRYj

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21751/discussion-between-nagaraj436-and-teekib)

Comment: hi iam in chat..can u please come

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity
Try this code

```
Intent menuSettingsIntent = new Intent(CityAttractions.this, ShareOnFacebook.class);
                menuSettingsIntent.putExtra("facebookMessage", "Msg");
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(menuSettingsIntent).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), REQUEST_CODE);
```

and override onActivityResult

and dismiss the dialog here. may this help you

Comment: it already has one onActivityResult in the activity..ho can i call this

Comment: use different requestCode for this and use result for that requestCode in onActivityResult

Comment: startActivityForResult(new Intent(menuSettingsIntent).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), 1);    used this

Comment: did this  if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
   dialog.dismiss();
     }

Comment: you have to set the result when you want to dismiss the dialog in subactivity

Comment: @teekib  one more thing may it solve your problem    use this dialog in your ShareOnFacebook                                          Dialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CityAttractions.this, "","Please wait...", true);       
 dialog.show();  and dismiss this dialog where you want

Comment: what is that one thing..i didn't get u

Comment: @teekib use above dialog in onCreate of ShareOnFacebook Activity

Comment: its not woring...here is my activity http://pastebin.com/nHzKvqmY can u look at it plz and tell where to use